# Get collection length

Tags: backbone.js

Using backbone.js and trying to get data from `postsList` array I got this in chrome console.log

```
d {length: 0, models: Array[0], _byId: Object, _byCid: Object, constructor: function…}
  _byCid: Object
  _byId: Object
  length: 9
  models: Array[9]
  __proto__: f
```

When I'm trying to use `console.log(postsList.length)` I get 0, but there are 9 models inside. I don't know how to get number of them.

Comment: postsList.length should give you 9, are you sure you are calling it after the models are added to the collection? open the chrome console and try postsList.length and see what u get

Comment: What's the code leading up to this point?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, this is strange behaviour :)

Chrome displays object preview immediately after you have used `console.log`.
When you entered `console.log(collection)` it was empty (probably you have fetched model from the server). But at the moment when you expand the object in console Chrome displays actual object params at current moment.

Try this in console:

```
var object = {key1:{prop:true}};
console.log(object)
object.key2 = true;
console.log(object)
```

To get collection length use this way:

```
collection.fetch({context:collection}).done(function() {
  console.log(this.length)
});
```

### EDIT

No-no-no :)
Use `this.length` instead of `this.lenght`.

```
collection.fetch({context:collection}).done(function() {
    // equals to this.length
    console.log(this.size());
    // get all models from collection (array of Backbone.Models)
    console.log(this.models);
    // get all models from collection (like simple array of objects)
    console.log(this.toJSON());
    // get model with index 1
    console.log(this.at(1));
    // get model data with index 1
    console.log(this.at(1).toJSON());
    // get model with id `some-id`
    console.log(this.get('some-id'));
    // get models data where property `id_str` equals to `292724698935070722`
    console.log(this.where({id_str:'292724698935070722'}));
});
```

For more information look here:
http://backbonejs.org/#Collection

Comment: Thanks it really works! But there are some problems. Sometimes this.lenght value is udefined even if models are in place. And I got some errors on repeating same conde blocks again. 
Maybe you can help me with that "d" array. I really don't understand how it works and how to get something from it, because it has everythink. Can I receive params directly from it?

Comment: @Lucas take a look on explanation below `EDIT`. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 3):

I think Vitaliys answer is a little bit dangerous, because the passed option `{context: collection}` is:

- a) not mentioned in backbones documentation
- b) handled deep down in jQuery when fetch triggers some Ajax-call.

Instead the length of the fetched collection can be easily checked in the `success-` and `error-` callback of fetch, e.g.:

```
someCollection.fetch({
    success: function(collection) { // the fetched collection!
        if (collection.length) {
            // not empty
        } else {
            // empty
        }
    }
});
```

See http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch

Comment: The [context](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-81) option isn't well documented but is clearly intended to be used. `if (success) success.call(options.context, model, resp, options);` In the case of this answer, you're right that the context isn't necessary.