# Get Length of Variable

Tags: javascript

Trying to get the length of a variable `territories`, yet when I do `territories.length` it gives me `0`. When I use `console.log` and look in the JavaScript console, it shows

```
child 
{
    length: 0, 
    models: Array[0], 
    _byId: Object, 
    _events: Object, 
    _listenerId: "l11"
}
```

So the length is `0` but when I expand that, it says that the length is`9`. I want it to be `9`. How can I get `length:9`?

Comment: What's `territories`, can you give us a bit more details ?

Comment: In your example the length is indeed 0, when you say "when I expand that, it says that the length is 9" what do you mean ? What are you expanding ?

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov In the JavaScript console. See [this.](http://i.imgur.com/kjSOPXB.png)

Comment: Could you post the entire code you need to get your `child`?

Comment: @scrblnrd3 It has to do with BackboneJS. This is how `territories` is defined: `var Territories = Backbone.Collection.extend`

Comment: Please make a [jsFiddle](http://jsFiddle.net) for us

Comment: @scrblnrd3 is there a way to find the number of models?

Comment: @user3161730 In the example you've provided `models` is an array with the size of 0. How about you prepare a fiddle and let us take a look.

Comment: The problem you're having in your console is because your object is later by another script modified to length:9. This makes it show length:9 in your console, while it was still 0 when the script was running. To get a true capture of what the actual value of the object was, you can use `JSON.stringify(obj)`. That will capture the object at that moment, and show the true values of the object.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this to get the number of properties in any javascript object, at least in modern browsers:

```
Object.keys(myObj).length;
```

You could also do this manually, like this

```
Object.prototype.length=function(){
    var count=0;
    for(var i in this){
        if(this.hasOwnProperty(i)){
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Why is that giving me `5`?

Comment: I don't get how the length is 9; there are 5 properties in your object

Comment: Isn't this giving him the number of properties in an object ?

Comment: Yeah, I think I misunderstood the question

Comment: @scrblnrd3 I'm not understanding it myself if I'm honest. Maybe you're right :)

Answer (score 0):

Length is the right property, but it depends on what kind of variable territories is. The below code for a string example outputs 9.

```
var territories = "my string";
var length = territories.length;
alert(length);
```

Since in this case territories is actually a backbone collection, you can find more information about this issue from the following question: [Get collection length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527755/get-collection-length)

Unfortunately you can't save the fetched collection data because the fetch function in backbone is asynchronous. You need to use a callback function to do whatever you need done with the length property. For more information see [How to return value from an asynchronous callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-callback-function) and http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/

Comment: `territories` is not a string.

Comment: I see, it looks like this question may have already answered it for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527755/get-collection-length

Comment: How would I save this as a variable though?

Comment: It's not working anymore. When I use `console.log(x)` it gives me `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function`

Comment: Do you understand why?

Comment: I think it's because fetching the collection is an asynchronous action and you are trying to assign the variable before the call back has finished. This is a fairly complicated topic, so I would suggest posting a new question to get more responses. I'll edit my answer one more time and you can see if that works.